# classified ads: paid option with rules and commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I am trying to create a classifieds site like the site "leboncoin.fr".

I block me at establishing a system of paying options for the advertiser:

Paying options:

- promote your ad for one week (€ 30); for a month (80 €)
- add 7 photos and more
- add a logo

You will find an attached image of the example of boncoin

I know that the modules Trade and Rules must be used, but I can not get it to work.